# Spring Integration + Spring AMQP: How can I passing MessageProperties to int:service-activator?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, amqp, spring-amqp

Configs like this:

```
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter connection-factory="connectionFactory" queue-names="#{prop['mq.queue.logging']}"
  channel="emailLoggingChannel" message-converter="jsonMessageConverter" error-channel="errorChannel" />

<int:channel id="emailLoggingChannel"/>

<int:service-activator id="handleEmailLogging" input-channel="emailLoggingChannel"
  ref="emailLoggingService" method="insertOrUpdate"/>
```

My question is:
How can I passing properties of AMQP message to int:service-activator?
Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AMQP `MessageProperties` are mepped to the `MessageHeaders`.

By default only standard AMQP properties (headers) are mepped.

To map all of them including any custom properties you should use this

```
mapped-request-headers="*"
```

for the `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>`.

See more info in the  [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#d4e5854).

Comment: Thanks in advance, Artem.
Complement:
Use `@Header("x-custom-param")` or `@Headers Map<String, Object>` on method of service-activator to accepts MessageHeaders. see [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations) or [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/amqp.html)

Comment: Glad to here. If it is OK for you, so just accept an answer to close the question.